# Move image up they y-axis in eclipse

Tags: java, android, timer, imageview

I am making a game for androids using eclipse and I had some trouble trying to figure this out. I already have 2 images on my layout and I just want to figure out how to make them move one unit up the y axis with a timer that is repeatedly. Thanks alot for any help appreciate it!

Comment: I think timers and GUI don't like each other...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
final int interval = 1000; // one second


View myView = ...;
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do work
        myView.setY(myView.getY() + 1); 
        handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
   }
handler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: where would the timer go in that? it looks a bit confusing

Comment: @IzzyMachado the basic logic goes like this: you have a bit of code (in this case wrapped by the runnable) that gets called by the Handler via #post. Inside the runnable, it asks the Handler to call itself again after the interval passes (in this case 1 second). It's a recursive loop of Runnables of sorts. Does that make sense?

Comment: ok so where should i add in the delta time because i know thats an important part to?

Comment: see the interval variable